# can i apply notification when countdowntimer onfinish?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, countdowntimer

i was trying to build a watering plant reminder app. so im thinking i can do push notification onFinish. so i got it right here:

```
CountDownTimer cdt = viewHolder.myCounter;
            if (cdt == null) {
                cdt = new CountDownTimer(plant.getDaysUntilWater()*60000, 60000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        plant.setDaysUntilWater((int) ceil(millisUntilFinished/60000.0));
                        button.setText(Integer.toString((int) ceil(millisUntilFinished/60000.0)));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        button.setText(R.string.needwater);
                        button.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                                .setContentTitle(plant.getName())
                                .setContentText("I need water")
                                .setWhen(onFinish())
                                .build();
                    }
                };
                cdt.start();
```

but i encountered by .setWhen(onFinish()) cannot be applied in void, because it said 'setWhen(long)' in 'android.app.Notification.Builder' cannot be applied to '(void)' . i was wondering is there any a way to tackle this problem?

Comment: you can use void in setWhen, why do you put time in it? setWhen is `Set the time that the event occurred. Notifications in the panel are sorted by this time.`

Comment: finally i get it now, because of i use onfinish to the method i referencing. that would be useless haha. but can i ask why my notification didnt show up??. i just deleted setwhen.